# $\mathbf{B}A$ as a 2-group in a long fiber sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, higher-category-theory, classifying-spaces, higher-homotopy-groups

I am trying to digest the following statement about 2-group:

> [From nlab Observation 4.2](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-group#ExamplesForEquivalencesOf2Groups):
>
> "Let $A \to \hat G$ be the inclusion of a subgroup, exhibiting a central extension $A \to \hat G \to G$ with $G := \hat G/A$. Then this short exact sequence of groups extends to a long fiber sequence of 2-groups
>   $$
> A \to \hat G \to G \to \mathbf{B}A \to \mathbf{B}\hat G \to \mathbf{B}G \to \mathbf{B}^2 A
>   \,,
> $$
>   **where $\mathbf{B}A$ denotes the 2-group** given by the *crossed module 
>   $(A \to 1)$*, and similarly for the other cases."

**Question 1**: I understand the induced long fiber sequence. But I do not understand why $\mathbf{B}A$ is called a 2-group? Can someone help me on this? Also what is the emphasis on "given by the *crossed module 
$(A \to 1)$*"?

Here the connecting homomorphism $G \to \mathbf{B}A$ is presented in the category of crossed modules by a zig-zag / anafunctor whose left leg is the above weak equivalence:

**Question 2**: Am I correct that to discuss 2-group $\mathbf K$ in this context we need to have the classifying space $\mathbf{B}K$ such that both the homotopy groups of $\pi_1(\mathbf{BK}) \neq 0$ and $\pi_2(\mathbf{BK}) \neq 0$? For example, if $\mathbf K=K_1 \times \mathbf{B}K_2$, then 
$$\pi_1(\mathbf{BK}) = \pi_1(\mathbf{B}K_1) =  K_1$$ and 
$$\pi_2(\mathbf{BK})= \pi_2(\mathbf{B}^2K_2) = K_2.$$

Are these two conditions sufficient conditions?

Or are these two conditions only necessary conditions?

Answer (score 1):

A 2-group is a groupoid equipped with a monoidal structure in which every object is invertible. For a 1-object groupoid $BG$, the Eckmann-Hilton argument shows that $BG$ admits a unique strictly monoidal 2-group structure if and only if $G$ is abelian. The reference to crossed modules is because the latter are equivalent to 2-groups.

Your second question is a bit unclear, but if $K_2$ is abelian then there is indeed a 2-group $K_1\times BK_2$, a product of strictly monoidal groupoids.

Comment: thanks, Kevin, I appreciate this +1. Let me see whats next

Comment: I like to take $K_2$ is abelian, I wonder whether $K_1\times BK_2$ is indeed always a 2-group? I feel that it looks the usual 2-group requires more data than mine  $K_1\times BK_2$. But how do you know $K_1\times BK_2$ is a 2-group?

Comment: More generally, if $BK_2 \to \mathbb{K} \to K_1$, either you can view it as a group extension or as a fibration, is this new $\mathbb{K}$ is always a 2-group when $K_2$ is abelian? (of course $\mathbb{K} =K_1 \times BK_2$ is an example

Comment: As I suggested, it's because both terms in the product are 2-groups. Being strictly monoidal and having all objects invertible are properties closed under products.

Comment: Same for $$, is $$ a 2-group?

Comment: Same for , is  a 2-group for the general $BK2→→K1$?  (sorry just make sure)

Comment: I think the base should be $BK_2$ and the fiber $K_1$. Then it should work but I'm not certain.

Comment: I think you got it wrong, generally we have $BK_2→→K_1$.